# Quartz: repeat job always on monday through friday

Tags: .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have next trigger:

```
var resumeTasksTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("ResumeTasksTrigger", "Tasks")
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(15, IntervalUnit.Second))
    .WithSchedule(
        DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder
        .Create()
        .OnMondayThroughFriday())
    .Build();
```

Should this trigger works every week or just once? If it's right, i can't figure out how to set intifinity repeat with `IScheduleBuilder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will run forever unless you specify a end date:

```
ITrigger resumeTasksTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("ResumeTasksTrigger", "Tasks")
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(15, IntervalUnit.Second))
    .EndAt(DateBuilder.FutureDate(10, IntervalUnit.Year))
    .WithSchedule(
        DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder
        .Create()
        .OnMondayThroughFriday()
        .WithIntervalInMinutes(30)
        .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(10, 0))
        .EndingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(12, 0))
        )
    .Build();
```

You can use this code to check all the schedules for a defined trigger:

```
    private static void GetNextXFireTimes(ITrigger trigger, int triggersCount)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("List of next {0} schedules: ", triggersCount.ToString()));

        var dt = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();

        using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\TEMP\Quartz.net.Log.Log"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < triggersCount; i++)
            {
                if (dt == null)
                    break;

                file.WriteLine(dt.Value.ToLocalTime().ToString());

                dt = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(dt);
            }  
        }
    }
```